I'm trying to send a POST to an API in Delphi but I get Error 400. Ho can I debug this?
I'm a Delphi programmer and this is the first time for me to deal with HTTP.
I'm trying to send a POST request to an API, but I get back a 400 BAD REQEST error.
This is the code I'm using:
FormData := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
try
  // Add the file to the form data
  FormData.AddFile('file', FilePath, 'application/json');  // Content type for JSON file

  FormData.AddFormField('input_file_id', File_ID);
  FormData.AddFormField('completion_window:','"24h"');

  // sets the params for the HTTP request
  idHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'multipart/form-data';
  APIKey := 'Bearer ' + MY_API_Key;
  idHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Authorization', APIKey);

  Response := IdHTTP.Post(FinalURL, FormData);           // Eexec the POST request

  // parse the JSON string of the response
  JsonResponse := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(Response);
  try
    if JsonResponse <> nil then
    begin
      File_Upload_Response_Object.id := (JsonResponse.GetValue<string>('id')).ToInteger;
      // ... all the other params parsed ...
    end
    else
    begin
       File_Upload_Response_Object.ErrorCode := 1; // I send back an error of some type
    end;
  finally
    JsonResponse.Free;
  end;    
finally   
  FormData.Free;
  SSLHandler.Free;
  idHTTP.Free;
end;   

What am I doing wrong?
This is the content of the FHTTP.Proto thant seems to go into the "Result" of the post command:
($29A8C1E1820, '', $29A8C05F4A0, '', '', '', '', '', -1, -1, -1, -1, '', 'multipart/form-data', '', $29A8C05F680, 0, 0, '', 0, '', False, '', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)', '', '', '', $29A8D98AED0, False, nil, '', $29A8C1E1820, '', '', nil, ctNormal, Id_IPv4, '')  

I really can't see anything useful here.

Does the body of the response contain any information about why the request was bad?  (Bear in mind that sometimes websites return errors as HTML when you're expecting JSON, so you may need to parse the response as raw text to see what it contains.)  Otherwise you'd need to check with any documentation or support for the server you're accessing.  The request could be bad for any number of reasons unknown to us.

I edited my post to add the content of the FHTTPProto.Result content. Can you see anything useful?

I don't see anything informative there, sorry.  You'll need to find out from the server why the request was considered bad.

"I send back an error of some type" - you don't want to be verbose on what actually failed either - I guess both you server and client get what asked for. How about analyzing the response in raw instead of forcefully trying to parse it as JSON?

The problem is that there is no response. The program rises the exception and does not give any contento to the variable "response".

@SergioBonfiglio the body content of the error response is available in the ErrorMessage property of the raised EIdHTTPProtocolException exception. Otherwise, you can enable the hoNoProtocolErrorException and hoWantProtocolErrorContent flags in the TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions property to fill your Response variable. In this case, use IdHTTP.ResponseCode to know if the request succeeded or failed.

On this line:
FormData.AddFormField('completion_window:','"24h"');

You should not have a : on the key name. Also, are you sure the value should be quoted?
Try this:
FormData.AddFormField('completion_window','24h');

